# Howto use mutil-images to simulate the slow shutter speed of the SLR camera

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

When you use  slow shutter speed of the SLR camera to take photo . You can get special effect. for example http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v157/Oilfan94/Rocky%20Mountains%20-%202007/5856-FR-web.jpg.

Are there any possibilities that I use mutil-images to simulate these result. I mean take a series of photos from the same scene. Then merge these photos. I have tried to merge these images . but the effect is so bad

Comment: Can't see this being programming related, just use your favorite imaging program like Photoshop

Comment: I actually also need to do the same thing, programmatically. Not sure why you would flag this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a pixel value in a photograph corresponds to the amount of light that reached that point on the sensor while the shutter was open, I'd assume you could just do (pseudocode)

```
out(i, j) = sum(frame_n(i, j) for each n) / n
```

to get the average over the time interval.